# Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a docker container within which a headless chrome driver gets certain information from a website. When I run this python script locally without docker, it works perfectly. Now I'm trying to package it in a docker, but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
```

My guess is that chrome and chromedriver are not installed in a correct path. It's because when I add `RUN google-chrome --version` in a Dockerfile, this throws an error `google-chrome: not found`. Same for `RUN chromedriver --version`. So I assume the installed location is wrong, but I can't figure out how to troubleshoot further. Any help would be appreciated!

selenium==4.16.0
my MacOS version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.1.0: Mon Oct  9 21:28:45 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.41.9~6/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020 arm64

my Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9.6

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Install Chrome
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get install -fy && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install ChromeDriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run main.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

my .py file

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Initialize the web driver with disabled window
# driver_path = '/Users/makotomiyazaki/chromedriver-mac-arm64' # replace with the driver path on the machine
CHROME_PATH = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
options.add_argument('--v=1')
options.add_argument('--log-level=0')  # For verbose logging
options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
service = Service(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```